# For prime $p$ and $q$, $2p^2=1+q^2$ are there many solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For the primes $5$ and $7$, $$2 \times 5^2=1+7^2$$
and for the primes $29$ and $41$,
$$2 \times 29^2=1+41^2$$
Can you find more solutions with primes $p$ and $q$ such that,
$$2 \times p^2=1+q^2$$
and so become famous with a sequence for OEIS?

Comment: Rather than trying to edit the original, I just retyped it.

Comment: And again, it is still as unclear as the original.

Comment: This sequence is already on the OEIS - oeis.org/A104683

Comment: Check A104683 and the terms are NOT all primes.  I believe a fresh sequence is possible from this.

Comment: 7   5  x  prime     y  prime  \\
  41   29  x  prime     y  prime  \\  
  63018038201   44560482149  x  prime     y  prime  \\   
  19175002942688032928599   13558774610046711780701  x  prime     y  prime  \\

Comment: These are very LARGE primes!!  Then I am correct in saying that solutions are rare.  Do you want to try submitting it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168676/for-primes-p-and-q-2-cdot-p2-1q2-has-few-solutions

Answer (score 0):

The following PARI/GP code determines the solutions upto the $1000$ th solution.

```
? forstep(k=1,2000,2,w=quadunit(8)^k;s=component(w,2);t=component(w,3);if(ispseu
doprime(s,3)==1,if(ispseudoprime(t,3)==1,print([k,s,t]))))
[3, 7, 5]
[5, 41, 29]
[29, 63018038201, 44560482149]
[59, 19175002942688032928599, 13558774610046711780701]
?
```

If further such pairs of primes exist, both primes must have more than $\ 2\ 600\ $ digits.